# How to display multiple selected items side by side with jquery chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-chosen, selectlistitem

My script is as follows. I got PersonList by  **$.getJSON()**, and I want to display all the elements in the PersonList side by side by using Jquery-chosen. But only the last item is displayed.

Thanks for your helps.

> 

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#raporNo").on('change', function () {
        var yId = $(this).val();

        $.getJSON("../Ekranlar/GorevlendirilenAdliBilUzmanlariGetir", { xId: yId },
            function (PersonList) {

                $("#chosenDropDown2").empty();

                $.each(PersonList, function (index, itemData) {

                    $("#chosenDropDown2").append("<option>" + itemData.Text + "</option>");
                    $("#chosenDropDown2").val(itemData.Text);
                    $("#chosenDropDown2").trigger("chosen:updated");

                });                 
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to set the value of your chosen element to use all the values returned from the server? Does the dropdown underneath get all of it's options as expected?

Perhaps all you need to do is set the selected attribute on all the options to true, then trigger the update on chosen once.

```
$.each(PersonList, function (index, itemData) {
    $("#chosenDropDown2").append("<option>" + itemData.Text + "</option>");
});
$("#chosenDropDown2 option").attr("selected", "selected");true
$("#chosenDropDown2").trigger("chosen:updated");
```